# How to copy partial selected/highlighted text within cell to clipboard, in excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

If cell value is:

```
Partial Text
```

I would like a user to highlight:

```
Partial
```

and have VBA to grab it to a string variable such as

```
foo = "Partial"
```

Much like I can use

```
bar = selection.value
```

Is this possible? If it isn't I'm thinking of ways to somehow copy that part of text and accessing clipboard with VBA to achieve this, but hopefully there is something simpler.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While accessing a cell, no VBA will be executed. And also can't be called. No workaround so far... sorry.

But you could change background or font color and catch this later... but to get text from the clipboard is easier then checking cell text character by character...

To get data from clipboard you need `.GetFromClipboard`...
[Please read this.](http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-get-text-from-the-windows-clipboard/)